# Button Resizing back to original size after animation completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I am trying to animate the resizing of a a uibutton.

Problem is that it goes back to its original size as soon as the animation has been completed. What is the problem here

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [self.btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(self.btn1.frame.origin.x, self.btn1.frame.origin.y, self.btn1.frame.size.width, 51)];
    [self.btn2 setFrame:CGRectMake(self.btn2.frame.origin.x, self.btn2.frame.origin.y, self.btn2.frame.size.width, self.btn2.frame.size.height/2)];
    [self.btn3 setFrame:CGRectMake(self.btn3.frame.origin.x, self.btn3.frame.origin.y, self.btn3.frame.size.width, self.btn3.frame.size.height/2)];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:20 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [self.slider setFrame:CGRectMake(10, self.slider.frame.origin.y, self.slider.frame.size.width, self.slider.frame.size.height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}];
```

Comment: check if else where you are setting frame of buttons! may be that method called after animation is completed

Comment: above snippet is the only place where i am doing any sort of resizing.

Comment: put break-point and check for flow where it goes after animation

Comment: I have checked and it just exits. As i said this is the only snippet of code in the whole project.

Comment: where you define btn1,btn2?

Comment: interface builder i am using an outlet to access them

Comment: Ok the problem was that i had autolayout enabled.I disabled it and now it doesn't go back to its original size